# Error on RadioButton Checked event

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

Here is xaml codes for your testing needs.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="325">
<Grid>
    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" IsChecked="True" GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Select" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" GroupName="MyGroup" Content="Select" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
    <Menu x:Name="Menu1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0">
        <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem1" Header="Saving">
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem2" Header="Save"/>
            <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem3" Header="Don't save"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Following code is working great.

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub RadioButton1_Unchecked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Unchecked
    Menu1.IsEnabled = False
End Sub
End Class
```

Following code is **not** working. Do you know why?

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub RadioButton1_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Checked
    Menu1.IsEnabled = True
End Sub
End Class
```

Error picture:

[image]

Comment: Do you think it would be helpful to include the exception message, or would you like us to guess?

Comment: Also don't tag spam

Comment: Because your `RadioButton` node is above from the `Menu` node. The `Checked` event will occur before `Menu1` created. You have to check the `Menu1` is not `null`. I want to show code but I don't know VB well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `RadioButton` node is above from the `Menu` node. The `Checked` event will occur before `Menu1` created. 
You have to check the `Menu1` is not `null`.

```
if (null != Menu1)
    Menu1.IsEnabled = true;
```

And place `IsEnabled="True"` to `Menu` node for default state.

```
<Menu x:Name="Menu1" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,50,0,0">
```

Comment: Thanks. Solved. Vb version: `If Menu1 IsNot Nothing Then Menu1.IsEnabled = True End If`